# d3 mapping numbers with scale

Tags: d3.js

If I set scales so points are in scale on the svg with:

```
d3.scale.linear().domain(xDomain).range([0, width]);
```

How can I get the unscaled number of the mouse x position?

**Eg.**

```
xPositions = [1,7,10]
```

7 is @ x = ~300 on an svg of width 500

How would I map 300 to 7 based on arbitrary data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`scale.invert` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_invert) for the inverse mapping:

```js
var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain(xDomain).range([0, width]);
var xDomainPos = [1, 7, 10];
var xRangePos = xDomainPos.map(function (d) { return xScale(d); });
var xNewDomainPos = xRangePos.map(function (d) { return xScale.invert(d); });
```